# What does unsubscribe() do in this firebase auth sample?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

On this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-2 there is a code sample where a function calls itself (see text in bold below) -- I'm confused what this means, can anybody please shed some light -- why does unsubscribe call itself?

```
  console.log('Google Auth Response', googleUser);
  // We need to register an Observer on Firebase Auth to make sure auth is initialized.
  var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
    unsubscribe();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) "adds an observer/listener for changes to the user's sign-in state" **AND** returns an unsubscribe function that can be called to cancel the listener.

So the goal of the following pattern

```
var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
    unsubscribe();

    // ...
});
```

is to listen **only once** for changes to the user's sign-in state. The first time the listener is triggered it calls the unsubscribe function, so it doesn't listen anymore.

As explained in the comment in the code you refer to, they use this pattern in order to make sure `auth` is initialized.

---

Note that one could have very well done:

```
var foo = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
    foo();

    // ...
});
```

Comment: Adding on to this answer: When you first load a page and a user had logged in previously, Firebase Authentication has to send a request to the authentication server to get a new access token for the session if needed. Using `onAuthStateChanged` this way essentially says "wait until the user is ready to use".

Comment: I'm not sure why the SDK doesn't have a Promise-based method for this pattern unless they want to discourage it.